# Merge two wordpress sites

Tags: import, export

I have been looking for an way to export 40.000 posts and 20.000 media files from one wordpress site (site A) to another site (site B). Site B already have data.

1. If I do a export and import directly in the database (phpmyadmin) I get problems with duplicates same ID. Any ideas how to solve that?
2. If I use the standard export / import feature in edit I get timeout or errors after 30 min. (To much data, I guess)

Any ideas how I can solve this. How would you merge two wordpress sites?
Thank you.

Best regards,
Steffan

Answer (score 0):

You can always divide the exported CSV file into parts and then import it on the other site.

A better option will be if the other site has comparatively less data then you can export it and import it on the first site and then perform a database switch.

I am not sure if any plugins exist for this as I used the first option when I was in a similar situation.

Let me know if this helps.